# How to implement Javascript functions properly in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I've got a project due soon for a class where I need to make a program that somehow uses Javascript, and I decided to make a page that displays random facts when a user inputs a number between 1 - 5; each number has its own set of facts, and will only display those facts (facts about 2 won't display when the user inputs a 1). I could do it all in JS but I'd rather use HTML and CSS as that's what I'm used to. My issue is not knowing how to get the JS functionality to work with an external JS file in HTML. For example, here's a block of code in HTML that shows a group of facts when a user inputs the number 1

```
<p>The FIRST music video on MTV was for the song "Video Killed the Radio Star", by the English new wave group The Buggles, and premiered on August 1, 1981 at 12:01 AM</p>
<p>The FIRST McDonald's restauarant opened in San Bernardino, CA, on May 15, 1940</p>
<p>The FIRST ever mobile phone call was made on April 3, 1973, by Martin Cooper, a senior engineer at Motorola</p>
<p>The FIRST photo of lightning was taken on September 2, 1882, by William Jennings, who wanted to know if lightning really had a zigzag form</p>
<p>The FIRST person to ever go down Niagara Falls in a barrel was 63-year-old Annie Edison Taylor, who was a widowed teacher. She made no money from her stunt</p>
<p>The FIRST Apple computer, developed and designed by Steve Wozniak and presented by Steve Jobs, was released on April 11, 1976</p>
<br /><br />
```

In JS, I could do this and it'd work fine (same pattern for 2-5)

```
enterNumber = prompt("Enter any number between from 1-5");
enterNumber = parseInt(enterNumber);

if (enterNumber == 1) {
        document.write("The FIRST music video on MTV was for the song 'Video Killed the Radio Star', by the English new wave group The Buggles, and premiered on August 1, 1981 at 12:01 AM" + PA);
        document.write("The FIRST McDonald's restauarant opened in San Bernardino, CA, on May 15, 1940" + PA);
        document.write("The FIRST ever mobile phone call was made on April 3, 1973, by Martin Cooper, a senior engineer at Motorola" + PA);
        document.write("The FIRST photo of lightning was taken on September 2, 1882, by William Jennings, who wanted to know if lightning really had a zigzag form" + PA);
        document.write("The FIRST person to ever go down Niagara Falls in a barrel was 63-year-old Annie Edison Taylor, who was a widowed teacher. She made no money from her stunt" + PA);
        document.write("The FIRST Apple computer, developed and designed by Steve Wozniak and presented by Steve Jobs, was released on April 11, 1976" + PA);
    }
```

What I'm basically trying to do is have all the JS functionality (prompt, if else, etc) work along with my HTML and CSS files, and unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to set all that up properly. How would I go about having a working page in this instance, where the JS functions would still work with what I have in HTML and CSS?

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#A_Hello_world!_example

Comment: Use a `<script>` tag in the head of your HTML document, and access your HTML elements with `document.querySelector("#elementid")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we get into your specific question, I have to say that any class/instructor you are taking that is teaching you `document.write()` is one that you should immediately ask for your money back on. `document.write()` has very limited use cases in modern JavaScript and definitely should not be used like you are using it. Anyone teaching you this clearly doesn't really know JavaScript and the Document Object Model.

As for your question, you need to decide "when" you want the JavaScript to run and then set up an event handler for that moment in time.

See comments inline below.

```js
// Prepare your static data ahead of time and store it in an array.
// Here we have one array, with 3 child arrays inside of it (one for each
// question.
let facts = [

   ["The FIRST music video on MTV was for the song 'Video Killed the Radio Star', by the English new wave group The Buggles, and premiered on August 1, 1981 at 12:01 AM",
"The FIRST McDonald's restauarant opened in San Bernardino, CA, on May 15, 1940",
"The FIRST ever mobile phone call was made on April 3, 1973, by Martin Cooper, a senior engineer at Motorola",
"The FIRST photo of lightning was taken on September 2, 1882, by William Jennings, who wanted to know if lightning really had a zigzag form",
"The FIRST person to ever go down Niagara Falls in a barrel was 63-year-old Annie Edison Taylor, who was a widowed teacher. She made no money from her stunt",
"The FIRST Apple computer, developed and designed by Steve Wozniak and presented by Steve Jobs, was released on April 11, 1976"
   ],
   
   [
    "some fact",
    "some fact",
    "some fact"
   ],
   [
    "some other fact",
    "some other fact",
    "some other fact"
   ]

];

// Set up a function that will run when the button is clicked
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", getFacts);

function getFacts(){

  // Always supply the second, optional (radix) argument to parseInt()
  let number = parseInt(prompt("Enter any number between from 1-5"), 10);

  // Prevent bad numbers
  if (number > facts.length || number < 0){
    alert("Bad input! Try again.");
    return;
  }

  // Get a reference to the <div> in the document where the output should go
  let output = document.getElementById("facts");

  // Separate each string in the appropriate sub-array with <br>
  // and populate the output element with all of them
  output.innerHTML = facts[number-1].join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<button>Get the facts!</button>
<!-- This empty div will eventually be populated with
     the relevant facts. -->
<div id="facts"></div>
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the suggestion :) What if I didn't want to use the button to bring up the prompt, and just have it be shown as the user opens the page?

Comment: @FranklinSantos Then remove the `button` and extract all the contents of the function from the function and just use that without the function.

Comment: So you mean get rid of the function and kinda have its contents on its own, without the `getFacts` being involved?